# Is possible to program LCD 20X2 display using parallel port?

Tags: c#, .net, lcd, parallel-port

I'd like to use a LCD DISPLAY using C#, while I was searching I realized several persons uses PICS to do this, I just want to know if this is possible using this language?

And if it's possible, some information related to this.c

Comment: I removed the `parallel` tag from your question as it is about parallel programming and has nothing to do with programming of the parallel I/O port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Note that ideally you'll want to use an LCD with a parallel controller.

This project is an example of exactly what you describe:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5081/I-O-Ports-Uncensored-Part-2-Controlling-LCDs-Liqui

The author suggests some LCD modules that will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually typed (bit wise) check the command response of your display, you could use "LPT-Display.exe" (for windows) from [www.berndjager.de/LPT-Display/overview.htm](http://www.berndjager.de/LPT-Display/overview.htm)